# Memory leak if Bitmap get's raw data from Marshal.AllocHGlobal?

Tags: c#, bitmap, pinvoke, marshalling

I am not clear on the mechanics of native interop.

Suppose I do the following:

```
IntPtr nativeArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(stride * height);
someNativeCallToFillRawImageData(nativeArray, width, stride, height);
return new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, nativeArray);
```

My allocated array then is the source of the bitmap (it works), but I am unsure if the memory for it will ever be cleared?

Alternatively, I can do the following (by changing DLLImport signature...native method is originally defined as (unsigned char *buff)):

```
byte[] managedArray = new byte[stride * height];
someNativeCallToFillRawImageData(managedArray, width, stride, height);
fixed (byte* ptr = managedArray)
{
   return new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr));
}
```

which also works, but I am not clear on the difference exactly. I am also under the impression that the first variant is faster, due to it not having to cross managed/unmanaged boundiers.

Does a managed Bitmap object dispose of the data in Scan0, even though it was allocated by someone else?
bitmap.Dispose() -> what happens to allocated memory in either managedArray or nativeArray ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to allocate the memory yourself. Create an empty bitmap with the desired size, then call LockBits to access the raw pixel data:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(width, height);
BitmapData data = null;
try
{
    data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    someNativeCallToFillRawImageData(data.Scan0, data.Width, data.Stride, data.Height);
}
finally
{
    if (data != null)
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

This way, the memory is handled by the `Bitmap` object, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thank you, that works too. I didn't think about just giving it the Scan0 directly.
After finally finding the docs for the Bitmap Constructor, I think this is the more correct way. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

If using Marshal.AllocHGlobal and the bitmap copies data from the pointer, you should free it with Marshal.FreeHGlobal.
I advice you read MSDN on the BitMap constructor as to if it copies the data or just uses the pointer; if it just uses the pointer you have to wait with freeing it.

Comment: You are right of course. I turns out that: "The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released."

So if I understand correctly, I would be leaking memory if I did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Dispose method in a class which uses unmanaged resource (nativeArray in your case) and free it using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeArray )`. Something like this:

```
if(nativeArray != IntPtr.Zero)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(nativeArray);
```

You are responsible to call created Dispose method.